# I cannot see my tables that I created in the H2 database in the H2 Console

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

I can not see my tables in the H2 console. I have created entities named "Users" and "Post".
I started the project and could not see them in the h2 console. What is the problem with my code? (All entities have a repository by the way.)

It is my application.properties :

```
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=4141
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.h2.console.enabled=true`
```

User Entity :

```
`@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "T_USER")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    //@Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String userName;

    //@Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    //@Column(name = "FULLNAME")
    private String fullName;

    //@Column(name = "PROFILE_PIC")
    private String profilePicture;

    //@Column(name = "BIO")
    private String bio;

    //@Column(name = "CREATED_AT")
    private Integer createdAt;
}
`
```

Post Entity :

```
`@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    //@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

//    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
//    private User user;

    //@Column(name = "IMAGE")
    private String image;

    //@Column(name = "CREATED_AT")
    private Integer createdAt;
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

On file **application.properties**

Try add:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following application property

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

This will enable the table creation from the entity classes.